# Trying to manually reset a Toshiba Satellite C55-A5310

Tags: bios, passwords, reset

How do I bypass BIOS password Toshiba Satellite C55-A5310 to factory settings without a disk or removing any parts?

Comment: I could flag this question, as a duplicate, of the duplicate of the duplicate that was selected.  However, in reality, most modern firmware passwords CANNOT be removed and those duplicates don't make that clear.

Comment: I had the same issue, however this is an evergreen question.